# Gitlab: Dependency scanner report is not shown on security dashboard

Tags: security, gitlab, dependencies, gitlab-ci

I am trying to create my own security scanner which will check dependencies. To test the functionality, I created a "mock scanner" which downloads a file from webhook, and saves it as an artifact ought to be uploaded to the server.

The artifact is uploaded successfully and in the CI output I can see the 201 code, but for some reason it is not presented in the security dashboard.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

The CI job looks as following:

```html
mysec_dependency_scanning:
  stage: test
  script: 
    - curl https://webhook.site/XXXX -o gl-dependency-scanning-report.json
    - sleep 3
  allow_failure: true
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dependency_scanning: gl-dependency-scanning-report.json
```

The content of the json file is from the example provided by gitlab and it as following:

```html
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "vulnerabilities": [
    {
      "id": "51e83874-0ff6-4677-a4c5-249060554eae",
      "category": "dependency_scanning",
      "name": "alik alik",
      "message": "Regular Expression Denial of Service in debug",
      "description": "alik to regular expression denial of service when untrusted user input is passed into the `o` formatter. It takes around 50k characters to block for 2 seconds making this a low severity issue.",
      "severity": "Unknown",
      "solution": "Upgrade to latest versions.",
      "scanner": {
        "id": "dadada",
        "name": "dadada"
      },
      "location": {
        "file": "yarn.lock",
        "dependency": {
          "package": {
            "name": "debug"
          },
          "version": "1.0.5"
        }
      },
      "identifiers": [
        {
          "type": "gemnasium",
          "name": "Gemnasium-37283ed4-0380-40d7-ada7-2d994afcc62a",
          "value": "37283ed4-0380-40d7-ada7-2d994afcc62a",
          "url": "https://deps.sec.gitlab.com/packages/npm/debug/versions/1.0.5/advisories"
        }
      ],
      "links": [
        {
          "url": "https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/534"
        },
        {
          "url": "https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/501"
        },
        {
          "url": "https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/pull/504"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "5d681b13-e8fa-4668-957e-8d88f932ddc7",
      "category": "dependency_scanning",
      "name": "Authentication bypass via incorrect DOM traversal and canonicalization",
      "message": "Authentication bypass via incorrect DOM traversal and canonicalization in saml2-js",
      "description": "Some XML DOM traversal and canonicalization APIs may be inconsistent in handling of comments within XML nodes. Incorrect use of these APIs by some SAML libraries results in incorrect parsing of the inner text of XML nodes such that any inner text after the comment is lost prior to cryptographically signing the SAML message. Text after the comment, therefore, has no impact on the signature on the SAML message.\r\n\r\nA remote attacker can modify SAML content for a SAML service provider without invalidating the cryptographic signature, which may allow attackers to bypass primary authentication for the affected SAML service provider.",
      "severity": "Unknown",
      "solution": "Upgrade to fixed version.\r\n",
      "scanner": {
        "id": "dadada",
        "name": "dadada"
      },
      "location": {
        "file": "yarn.lock",
        "dependency": {
          "package": {
            "name": "saml2-js"
          },
          "version": "1.5.0"
        }
      },
      "identifiers": [
        {
          "type": "gemnasium",
          "name": "Gemnasium-9952e574-7b5b-46fa-a270-aeb694198a98",
          "value": "9952e574-7b5b-46fa-a270-aeb694198a98",
          "url": "https://deps.sec.gitlab.com/packages/npm/saml2-js/versions/1.5.0/advisories"
        },
        {
          "type": "cve",
          "name": "CVE-2017-11429",
          "value": "CVE-2017-11429",
          "url": "https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2017-11429"
        }
      ],
      "links": [
        {
          "url": "https://github.com/Clever/saml2/commit/3546cb61fd541f219abda364c5b919633609ef3d#diff-af730f9f738de1c9ad87596df3f6de84R279"
        },
        {
          "url": "https://github.com/Clever/saml2/issues/127"
        },
        {
          "url": "https://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/475445"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "remediations": [
    {
      "fixes": [
        {
          "id": "5d681b13-e8fa-4668-957e-8d88f932ddc7",
        }
      ],
      "summary": "Upgrade saml2-js",
      "diff": "ZGlmZiAtLWdpdCBhL...OR0d1ZUc2THh3UT09Cg==" // some content is omitted for brevity
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix the problem, the issue was an invalid json format.
Had to do alot of trial and error but I was able to create a working template for a dependency scanning report.

```js
{
  "version": "3.0.0",
  "vulnerabilities": [
    {
      "id": "dfa1f7f3d56db6e1c3451a232de42f153e0335611de6f0344443d84e448ee2cf",
      "category": "dddda",
      "name": "dddda",
      "message": "ddda",
      "description": "dddda lack of validation in `index.js`.",
      "cve": "dada",
      "severity": "Critical",
      "solution": "Upgrade to version 2.0.5 or above.",
      "scanner": {
        "id": "lalal",
        "name": "Code_Analyzer"
      },
      "location": {
        "file": "yarn.lock",
        "dependency": {
          "iid": 447,
          "package": {
            "name": "copy-props"
          },
          "version": "2.0.4"
        }
      },
      "identifiers": [
        {
          "type": "dada",
          "name": "dada-e9e12690-2e4d-4251-bef0-7357ddc05881",
          "value": "e9e57890-5e4d-4832-bef2-7337ddc05889",
          "url": "https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/security-products/gemnasium-db/-/blob/master/npm/copy-props/CVE-2219-28503.yml"
        },
        {
          "type": "cve",
          "name": "CVE-2237-28503",
          "value": "CVE-2237-28503",
          "url": "https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2237-28503"
        }
      ],
      "links": [
        {
          "url": "https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2237-28503"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "remediations": [],
  "dependency_files": [
    {
      "path": "yarn.lock",
      "package_manager": "yarn",
      "dependencies": [  
          {
            "iid": 447,
            "dependency_path": [
              {
                "iid": 708
              },
              {
                "iid": 707
              }
            ],
            "package": {
              "name": "copy-props"
            },
            "version": "2.0.4"
          }
        ]
    }
  ],
  "scan": {
  "scanner": {
    "id": "lalal",
    "name": "Code_Analyzer",
    "url": "https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/security-products/analyzers/gemnasium",
    "vendor": {
      "name": "lalal"
    },
    "version": "2.29.5"
  },
  "type": "dependency_scanning",
  "start_time": "2021-05-03T06:47:29",
  "end_time": "2021-05-03T06:47:30",
  "status": "success"
  }
}
```